# Line right after text

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a line that starts right after my text on the same line, I've tried with the following simple code

```
<html><body>My Text<hr/></body></html>
```

It seems that `<hr>` is not an option because it is always on a new line and I'd like the line to start at the right of my text.

Any help ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this line? The reason the HR appears below(by default) is that's the entire point: that tag is supposed to indicate a divider. If the line you're trying to achieve is just decorative, there are more appropriate ways to approach this. (I take a shot at it below.) There's also a little leeway in this question for interpretation; you might want to add an image of exactly what it is you mean by "on the same line."

Comment: `<table><tr><td>&lt;TL;DR&gt;<td style="width: 100%;"><hr><td><i>fini</i></table>`

Answer (score 22):

Using FlexBox Property this can be achieved easily.

```css
.mytextdiv{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
   align-items: center;
}
.mytexttitle{
  flex-grow:0;
}

.divider{
  flex-grow:1;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #9f9f9f;
}
```

```html
<div class="mytextdiv">
  <div class="mytexttitle">
    My Text
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

The `<hr>` has default styling that puts it on a new line. However that default styling can be over-ridden, in the same way as it can for any other element. `<hr>` is in essence nothing more than an empty `<div>` with a default border setting.

To demonstrate this, try the following:

```
<div>Blah blah<hr style='display:inline-block; width:100px;' />dfgdfg</div>
```

There are a number of ways to override the styling of `<hr>` to acheive your aim.

You could try using `display:inline-block;` along with a `width` setting, as I have above. The down-side of this approach is that it requires you to know the width you want, though there are ways around this - `width:100%;`, and the whole line in a container `<div>` that has `overflow:hidden;` might do the trick, for example:

```
<div style='overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;'>Blah blah<hr style='display:inline-block; width:100%;' /></div>
```

Another option would be to use `float:left;`. You'd need to apply this to all the elements in the line, and I dislike this option as I find that `float` tends to cause more problems than it solves. But try it and see if it works for you.

There are various other combinations of styles you can try - give it a go and see what works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`<html><body>My Text<hr style="float: right; width: 80%"/></body></html>`

The inline CSS `float: right` will keep it on the same line as the text.
You'll need to adjust the `width` if you want it to fill the rest of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Using `inline` or `float`, as far as I tested it doesn't work properly even if this was my first thought. Looking further I used the following css

```
hr {
    bottom: 17px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

div {
    background:white;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**html**

```
<div>My Text</div><hr/>
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mFEWk/

What I did, is to add position relative in both elements (to give me the advantage of `z-index` use). Also from the moment I had `position:relative` for `hr` I moved it from the `bottom:17px`. This move it above the `div` that contains the text. Applying `z-index` values and adding `background:white` for the `div` puts the text above the the line. Of course don't forget to use a `width` for the text, otherwise will take the whole width of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style="float: left">Some text</div>
<hr style="clear: none; position: relative; top: 0.5em;">
```

Exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works

```
<p style="float:left;">
    Hello Text
    <hr style="float:left; width: 80%"/>
</p>
```

You can also use this to draw a line between texts like

Hello -------------------------- Hello

Answer (score 1):

The OP never specified the purpose of the line, but I wanted to share what I ended up doing when I was making an html template where the user needed a line to write on after the document was printed.

Because the hr tag defaults to its own line and defaults to being centered in the line, I decided to use a div and style it instead.

**HTML**

```
This is my text.<div class='fillLine'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fillLine {
display:inline-block;
width: 200px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo**

[Style Div for Line After Text](https://jsfiddle.net/persononfire/9ha1x8pe)

Hope that helps anyone who had the same goal as me.

Answer (score 0):

```
hr {
width: {so it fits on the same line as the p tag};
}
p {
float: left;
width: {enough to accomodate the hr};
}
```

That sort of make sense?

```
<p>My text</p>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one potential approach, but it has some assumptions/requirements. Your question should be edited to give more specific information about what you're building.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blah</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color : white;
            font-family : Arial;
            font-size : 16px;
        }
        .wrap {
            background: transparent url(px.png) repeat-x 0px 85%;
            /* Different fonts or text sizes may require tweaking of that offset.
               px.png is a one-pixel(though can be thicker if needed) image in whatever color you want the line */
        }
        .inner {
            background-color : white;
            /* Should match the background of whatever it's sitting over. 
               Obviously this requires a solid background. */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap"><span class="inner">Here is some text</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following technique:

Give the container div a background-image with a horizontal line. 
Put an element (like `<h3>`) in the container div (I have it on the right so `float: right;` )

Use the following css:

```
.line-container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 40px; 
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-image: url("/images/horizontal_line.png");
}

.line-container h3 {
  padding-left: 10px; 
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Below code did the job for me

HTML File:
----------
<p class="section-header">Details</p><hr>

CSS File:
----------
.section-header{
    float: left; 
    font-weight: bold
}

hr{
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

INLINE:
-------
<p style="float: left;font-weight: bold">Details</p><hr style="float: left;width: 80%;">
```